# Positioning JButton is not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

I have a decorated `JFrame`. I've added a background image to the frame and added a `JButton`.
When I add a button the background image is not visible. What should I do?
Here is my code snippet.

```
public Demo3()

{
    setTitle("STARTUP");
    setSize(800,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel jp=new JPanel();
    JButton jb=new JButton();
    JLabel jl=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("c://image.jpg"));
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jp.add(jl);
    jp.add(jb);

    add(jp);
    jb.setBounds(400,250,50,50);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: BTW - did you not understand my advice to post an SSCCE, or are you just ignoring it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the layout of JLabel null.Then only setBounds method will work.

lj,setLaout(null);

jb.setBounds(400,250,50,50);

Comment: -1, this is a terrible solution. You should not be using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You were given a much better solution a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a null layout.

See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a couple of options. Depending on your exact requirement you can:

1. use the JLabel as the background and then set the layout manager of the label
2. do custom painting on a panel and then add components to the panel.